# Run ajax request on document.ready jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../include/ListOfCities.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            Country: "Japan"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var city = ('#city');
            $(city).empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(city).append('<option id=' + data[i].sysid + ' value=' + data[i].city_name + '>' + data[i].city_name + '</option>');

            }
        }

    });
});
```

php

```
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Country']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM city_tbl WHERE country_name = ? ");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $citylist[] = array('sysid' => $selected_row['sys_id'], 'code' => $selected_row['city_code'], 'name' => $selected_row['city_name'], 'parentid' => $selected_row['parent_id']);
        }
        $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $citylist)));
        echo json_encode($input, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
```

I want to display the all the city in japan in a select option menu i want to load the cities when the page loads i am sending the ajax request like above but i don't get any result the ajax above works fine when i use it on button. Is sending ajax request different from on button click and on document ready..Any suggestion how to make ajax request on document ready is appreciated

Comment: Can you show your handler for the button click?..

Comment: i just add `$('#anybutton').click(function() {` above the line `$.ajax({` and i would run but i am trying to load the name when the page load so i remove the `onclick` event thinking it will load the name when the document is ready but it is not showing any console.log or options in select

Comment: Your code should work fine, did u see network request made in developer console - network tab ?

Comment: what do you mean by `should work fine` i get no error even from network tab what error should i expect from network tab?

Comment: Have you seen the ajax request in your network tab (of the developer console)?  If not, there must be something else in the code preventing `document.ready`.  Maybe just try putting the ajax request in the head of the page.

Comment: If you're on Chrome, open Developer Tools (F12), go to Network - click on Filter icon and select XHR, reload the page again using F5, if you don't see ur call there, then the call itself is not fired. You can check if there're are any errors in Console tab of Dev Tools. Also one more thing, are you sure that there's a `city` element in your page ?

Comment: @sideroxylon yes i am aware of the developer console because i have `console.log(data);` to data is showing i will check what you said also with arkantos i am having the ajax request from another page if this is of any significance

Comment: @Arkantos i can see my requert here in XHR it is here then maybe i get error in php select statement

Comment: `i am having the ajax request from another page`. Can you elaborate on this one ? till now i'm assuming that you're loading a page with some `select` element and on dom ready, you're trying to add options to that.. is it any different from wat ur doing ?

Comment: did u see click on ajax request and see the `Response` tab ? wat does it say ?

Comment: @Arkantos i didnt know about that response tab until now i was correct because the reposen is saying else actually i added else on the select so i have to work on the select statement

Comment: hopefully after your query change, it should work :)

Comment: @Arkantos yes hopefully why cant i upvote your comment the one that tells about the console?

Comment: i guess you don't enough reputation to do that :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just try setting `async:false` in your ajax request. So the final code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../include/ListOfCities.php',
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        data: {
            Country: "Japan"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var city = ('#city');
            $(city).empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $(city).append('<option id=' + data[i].sysid + ' value=' + data[i].city_name + '>' + data[i].city_name + '</option>');

            }
        }

    });
});
```